# Put a match on list and get Distinct Country Names

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint-2010, logic

On my front end there are 2 options to choose the Country, one is [Resident of : single Select DropDown List] and another is [Country's you Visited : Multiselect DropDown List] and all the values goes in SharePoint List, first as a Choose fields and another as a lookup `values (id#;#value,#id#;#value)`.

Now I have a search page where user can select criteria from Country drop-down : In order to load the dropdown I have selected all the distinct values from Resident of field, somehow I need to get the values from Country's visited as-well and load it in dropdown as distinct values.

I cannot think of a logic to extract distinct values from a multi-selected field and then compare it with a regular choose field values like below:

```
   Resident of             Countries Visited

a) Canada                  Chile,Argentina,Russia.
b) Peru                    Canada,Russia,Spain,Germany.
```

Now while loading the dropdown, how will I get the distinct values from the above list.

Comment: Are you searching for `String.Split(',')`?

Comment: We can split it and putt in one array, but again the complexity will occur while comparing it both sides, In order to get the Unique values.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string countries1 = "Chile,Argentina,Russia";
string countries2 = "Canada,Russia,Spain,Germany";
var countryLists = new List<string>() { countries1, countries2 };
var distinctCountries = countryLists.Select( s => s.Split(','))
    .SelectMany(list => list, (list, country) => country)
    .Distinct();
```

Explanation

- Create a collection of comma separated strings
- Use string.Split to project this into a collection of collections of strings
- Use SelectMany to flatten this into a single list
- Use Disting to remove duplicates

I couldn't tell from the question if you also want the resident list to be merged with this list. If you do, you need to do `Union(residentCountries)` instead of `Distinct()` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying @Mike Goodwin's answer a bit:

```
string countries1 = "Chile,Argentina,Russia";
string countries2 = "Canada,Russia,Spain,Germany";
var countryLists = new List<string>() { countries1, countries2 };
var distinctCountries = string.Join(",", countryLists).Split(',').Distinct();
```

Not sure that this answers the question, though.

Comment: Thanks Jesper, I definitely will try it soon and will post you if it fits the scenario.